# Convert a sparse matrix to dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix that stores computed similarities between a set of documents. The matrix is an ndarray.

```
         0         1         2         3         4          
0        1.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  
1        0.000000  1.000000  0.067279  0.000000  0.000000  
2        0.000000  0.067279  1.000000  0.025758  0.012039  
3        0.000000  0.000000  0.025758  1.000000  0.000000  
4        0.000000  0.000000  0.012039  0.000000  1.000000
```

I would like to transform this data into a 3-dimensional dataframe as follows.

```
docA docB similarity
1    2    0.067279
2    3    0.025758
2    4    0.012039
```

This final result does not contain matrix diagonals or zero values. It also lists each document pair only once (i.e. in one row only). Is there is a built-in / efficient method to achieve this end result? Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Output should also have (2,4,0.012039) entry?

Comment: @Nuageux yes - I missed that. corrected. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the dataframe to an array:

```
x = df.to_numpy()
```

Get a list of non-diagonal non-zero entries from the sparse symmetric distance matrix:

```
i, j = np.triu_indices_from(x, k=1)
v = x[i, j]
ijv = np.concatenate((i, j, v)).reshape(3, -1).T
ijv = ijv[v != 0.0]
```

Convert it back to a dataframe:

```
df_ijv = pd.DataFrame(ijv)
```

---

I'm not sure if this is any faster or anything but an alternative way to do the middle step is to convert the numpy array to an `ijv` or "triplet" sparse matrix:

```
from scipy import sparse
coo = sparse.coo_matrix(x)
ijv = np.concatenate((coo.row, coo.col, coo.data)).reshape(3, -1).T
```

Now given a symmetric distance matrix, all you need to do is to keep the non-zero elements on the upper right triangle. You could loop through these. Or you could pre-mask the array with `np.triu_indices_from(x, k=1)`, but that kind of defeats the whole purpose of this supposedly faster method... hmmm.